# Match multiple columns and print binary results

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I want to print the binary results for `file1` is the values are matches in `file2`:

file1:

```
a b c d
1 2 9 4
5 6 7 8
4 3 0 1
8 9 6 5
```

file2:

```
x
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Expected results:

```
a b c d
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 1
```

By matching column `x` in `file2` with all columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` in `file1`. I want to print binary result in `Result` file.

Comment: It looks such a very challenging problem. Anyway, what have you tried so far? Don't pretend us to solve it from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if(NR>1)a[$1];next}FNR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i in a?$i=1:$i=0}1' f2 f1
a b c d
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 1
```

Where `f2` and `f1` are your `file2` and `file1` respectively.

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea if you like that you should check out this [page](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

Comment: @sudo_O Thanks!! well thought